# Is there a way to make gradle task lintRelease do nothing when executed for a particular module?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Currently lintRelease, task depends on the compilation task, and for some modules (which I dont care about since its only used for testing purposes), I want lintRelease to do nothing, just print `Not supported` is that possible with gradle KTS?

Basically this question is about gradle task replacement, I want to replace the `lintRelease` gradle task with a task that does nothing.

If you are thinking

> You can skip lint checking for debug/release builds

The lintRelease task is manually triggered at the moment by a shell script, so thats not an option, I need this task to not do anything for this particular module lets call it module X

Comment: can you please explain more what do you want

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh Basically this question is about gradle task replacement, I want to replace the lintRelease gradle task with a task that does nothing.

Comment: you can skip lint checking for debug/release builds

Comment: The lintRelease task is manually triggerd, so thats not an option, I need this task to not do anything for this particular module lets call it module X

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the top of the Gradle file

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Even this can also help

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        tasks.lint.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks these are different from the ones i tried. let me give it a shot thanks

Comment: so basically if I run `./gradlew lintRelease` it should not execute anything just print `not supported` and end, I think above code is not doing that

Comment: it will skip the lint task, thats it, you can put this in X module's gradle file

Comment: not working because when i run `lintRelease` it will still execute all the steps in that task, including code compilation